# Getting values of fields in a task

Tags: ada

I'm trying to get the values of fields in a task. The `Worker` loop is quite huge, so I'm going to leave only the important part.
Basically, upon user entering "w", I would like the console to print info about those three fields.

[image]

Bonus question: Task body `Worker` have a loop, and I would like to make a "FinishedJob++" at the very end of it; but I have no idea how to do that either.

Comment: Would it be possible to copy the relevant parts of the code, as shown in the screenshot, into the question above. The code in the screenshot is hardly readable.

Comment: The code in the screenshots isn’t legible at all.

Comment: @SimonWright: Sadly, my initial edit failed to make the image clickable; see [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55889848/revisions).

Answer (score 3):

A task is not a record. It does not contain fields that can be directly accessed from outside the task. 
You can provide task entries to query the current value of a variable declared locally in a class, but remember that entries force synchronization upon the calling task and the called task.

The wording of your "bonus question" looks like C or C++ thinking. Ada is not simply C or C++ with begin and end replacing '{' and '}'.

What visibility do you want for the FinishedJob count? It appears you want to share that number with another task, such as the program main task. The easiest way to do that is to create a protected object incremented when the worker task completes is outer loop, and read whenever appropriate by the reading task(s).

A possible example of such a protected object is:

```
protected Counter is
   procedure Increment;
   entry Read(Num : out Natural);
private
   Tally : Natural := 0;
   Is_Updated : Boolean := False;
end Counter;

protected body Counter is
   procedure Increment is
   begin
      Tally := Tally + 1;
      Is_Updated := True;
   end Increment;

   entry Read(Num : out Natural) when Is_Updated is
   begin
      Num := Tally;
      Is_Updated := False;
   end Read;
end Counter;
```

The writer calls Counter.Increment upon completing its outer loop. The reader calls Counter.Read and gets the new value as soon as it is available.

Answer (score 2):

From what you show in the screen shots, it seems to me that you are looking for a way to configure a task/worker (`Worker_Id`, `Patient` (?)) and then, after the task/worker has been started, a way to monitor its progress (`Jobs_Done`).

Assuming the above, and given the important marks already made by Jim Rogers, it might  be interesting to know that tasks are typically configured via so-called task discriminants instead of initial `accept` entries. Task discriminants *are* accessible from outside the task (see [RM 9.1 (9)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-1.html#p9)) and immutable by definition. Hence, in your case, you might define two task discriminants as in

```
task type T_My_Task
   (Worker_Id : Natural;
    Patient   : Boolean);
```

which can be used as

```
declare
  T1 : T_My_Task  (1, True);
  T2 : T_My_Task  (2, True);
begin

  Put_Line (T1.Worker_Id'Image);
  Put_Line (T1.Patient'Image);

  Put_Line (T2.Worker_Id'Image);
  Put_Line (T2.Patient'Image);

end;
```

Out of my own interest, I tried to make some example program based on how I think you could approach this problem. I'm pretty sure more approaches exist and I will not claim that this is the best one. I included some comments to clarify what I (try to) do. It might be useful to you.

**NOTE**: I updated the example below with respect to what I initially posted as I was not satisfied with the initial design.

**main.adb** (main program)

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Work_Force;  use Work_Force;

procedure Main is

   Worker_Configs : T_Worker_Config_Array :=
     (0 => (Patient => True ),
      1 => (Patient => False),
      2 => (Patient => False),
      3 => (Patient => True ),
      4 => (Patient => False));

   package My_Work_Force is
     new Generic_Work_Force (Worker_Configs);
   use My_Work_Force;

   User_Response : Character;

begin

   Main_Loop: loop

      Put_Line ("--==[ MENU ]==--");
      New_Line;
      Put_Line (" S - Show status workers");
      Put_Line (" Q - Quit");
      New_Line;
      Put (" ==> "); Get (User_Response);
      New_Line;

      case User_Response is

         when 'S' =>

            for Worker_Id in T_Worker_Id'Range loop
               declare
                  Worker_Config : T_Worker_Config :=
                    Get_Worker_Config (Worker_Id);
                  Worker_Status : T_Worker_Status :=
                    Get_Worker_Status (Worker_Id);
               begin
                  Put_Line (" Worker. . . : " & Worker_Id'Image);
                  Put_Line (" Patient . . : " & Worker_Config.Patient'Image);
                  Put_Line (" Jobs_Done . : " & Worker_Status.Jobs_Done'Image);
                  New_Line;
               end;
            end loop;

         when 'Q' =>

            --  The call "Terminate_All_Workers" is actually a request. The
            --  call is non-blocking thanks to the protected object "Manager"
            --  in the "Work_Force" package. The program itself, however,
            --  will not terminate until all tasks have terminated (i.e.
            --  exited the "Worker_Loop" (see task body of "T_Worker").

            My_Work_Force.Terminate_All_Workers;
            Put_Line ("Program will end when all workers have terminated.");
            New_Line;
            exit Main_Loop;

         when others =>

            Put_Line ("(Unknown option)");
            New_Line;

      end case;

   end loop Main_Loop;

end Main;
```

**work_force.ads** (package spec; couldn't come up with a better name for now)

```
package Work_Force is

   --  Record type "T_Worker_Config" contains all items required to configure
   --  a worker. For now it contains only 1 item, but this can easily be
   --  extended.

   type T_Worker_Config is
      record
         Patient : Boolean;
      end record;

   type T_Worker_Config_Array is
     array (Natural range <>) of aliased T_Worker_Config;


   --  Record type "T_Worker_Status" contains all items related tot the status
   --  of the worker. As for type "T_Worker_Config", it now contains only 1
   --  item, but this can easily be extended.

   type T_Worker_Status is
      record
         Jobs_Done : Natural;
      end record;


   generic
      Workers_Config : T_Worker_Config_Array;      
   package Generic_Work_Force is

      --  The package "Generic_Work_Force" exposes a restricted set of
      --  subprograms such to have proper interface/implementation decoupling
      --  (and reduce the impact of changes in the implementation, etc.).

      subtype T_Worker_Id is
        Natural range Workers_Config'Range;

      function Get_Worker_Config
        (Worker_Id : T_Worker_Id) return T_Worker_Config;
      --  Gets the configuration from the worker "Worker_Id". A call to
      --  this subprogram is non-blocking.

      --  NOTE: "Get_Worker_Config" is not strictly necessary as the
      --  "Workers_Config" parameter of the generic package can be accessed
      --  directly from outside the package, but it looks nice and symmetric
      --  with respect to the subprogram "Get_Worker_Status" below.

      function Get_Worker_Status
        (Worker_Id : T_Worker_Id) return T_Worker_Status;
      --  Gets the status from the worker "Worker_Id". A call to this
      --  subprogram is non-blocking.

      procedure Terminate_All_Workers;
      --  Request to terminate all workers. A call to this subprogram is
      --  non-blocking.

      --  NOTE: there is no private part in this spec as there are no
      --  private types defined in the public part of the spec. All
      --  implementation details can reside in the body such that they
      --  can change independently from the spec, if necessary, without 
      --  the need to touch the spec file.

   end Generic_Work_Force;

end Work_Force;
```

**work_force.adb** (package body)

```
package body Work_Force is

   package body Generic_Work_Force is

      -------------
      -- Manager --
      -------------

      --  Protected object instance "Manager" is a synchronized 
      --  data object that administrates common requests to all workers.

      protected Manager is

         procedure Request_Termination;
         --  Requests the termination of the workers.
         --  ===> To be called from another task (e.g. the program main task).

         function Is_Termination_Requested return Boolean;
         --  Returns True if the termination is requested.
         --  ===> To be called from a worker task.

      private
         Termination_Requested : Boolean := false;
      end Manager;

      protected body Manager is

         procedure Request_Termination is
         begin
            Termination_Requested := True;
         end Request_Termination;

         function Is_Termination_Requested return Boolean is
         begin
            return Termination_Requested;
         end Is_Termination_Requested;

      end Manager;


      -------------------
      -- T_Worker_Data --
      -------------------

      --  Protected object type "T_Worker_Data" is a synchronized 
      --  data type that administrates dynamic worker data that must
      --  be shared with other tasks.

      protected type T_Worker_Data is      

         procedure Report_Job_Done;
         --  Increments the "Jobs_Done" counter.
         --  ===> To be called from a worker task.

         function Get_Jobs_Done return Natural; 
         --  Returns the value of the "Jobs_Done" counter.
         --  ===> To be called from another task (e.g. the program main task).

      private
         Jobs_Done : Natural := 0;      
      end T_Worker_Data;

      protected body T_Worker_Data is

         ---------------------
         -- Report_Job_Done --
         ---------------------

         procedure Report_Job_Done is
         begin
            Jobs_Done := Jobs_Done + 1;
         end Report_Job_Done;

         -------------------
         -- Get_Jobs_Done --
         -------------------

         function Get_Jobs_Done return Natural is
         begin
            return Jobs_Done;
         end Get_Jobs_Done;

      end T_Worker_Data;


      --------------
      -- T_Worker --
      --------------

      --  Task type "T_Worker" is the actual worker. Note that the worker
      --  configuration, "Workers_Config (Worker_Id)", is visible to the
      --  task as it is a parameter to the generic package.

      task type T_Worker
        (Worker_Id   : T_Worker_Id;
         Worker_Data : access T_Worker_Data); 

      task body T_Worker is

         --  Just to show how to access the worker's configuration.
         Patient : Boolean := Workers_Config (Worker_Id).Patient;
         pragma Unreferenced (Patient);

      begin
         Worker_Loop: loop    

            if Manager.Is_Termination_Requested then
               exit Worker_Loop;
            end if;

            --  Do some work...
            delay (Worker_Id * 0.1 + 0.2);

            --  Maybe check the termination request somewhere half-way (if
            --  that's allowed, it might be that the worker must finish its job).

            if Manager.Is_Termination_Requested then
               exit Worker_Loop;
            end if;

            --  Continue the work...
            delay (Worker_Id * 0.1 + 0.2);

            --  Report job done.
            Worker_Data.Report_Job_Done;

         end loop Worker_Loop;
      end T_Worker;      


      --  Arrays that will hold the instances of "T_Worker" and "T_Worker_Data".
      --  The initialization will be done in the package initialization section
      --  which is executed during the elaboration of the package.
      Workers      : array (T_Worker_Id'Range) of access T_Worker;
      Workers_Data : array (T_Worker_Id'Range) of access T_Worker_Data; 


      -----------------------
      -- Get_Worker_Config --
      -----------------------

      function Get_Worker_Config
        (Worker_Id : T_Worker_Id) return T_Worker_Config
      is
      begin
         return Workers_Config (Worker_Id);
      end Get_Worker_Config;

      -----------------------
      -- Get_Worker_Status --
      -----------------------

      function Get_Worker_Status
        (Worker_Id : T_Worker_Id) return T_Worker_Status 
      is
      begin
         return (Jobs_Done => Workers_Data (Worker_Id).Get_Jobs_Done);
      end Get_Worker_Status;

      ---------------------------
      -- Terminate_All_Workers --
      ---------------------------

      procedure Terminate_All_Workers is
      begin
         Manager.Request_Termination;
      end Terminate_All_Workers;


      -- Start processing for Generic_Work_Force.

   begin

      --  This is the initialization sequence of the package which will be
      --  called during its elaboration.

      for Worker_Id in T_Worker_Id'Range loop

         Workers_Data (Worker_Id) :=
           new T_Worker_Data;

         Workers (Worker_Id) := 
           new T_Worker 
             (Worker_Id   => Worker_Id,
              Worker_Data => Workers_Data (Worker_Id));  

      end loop;

   end Generic_Work_Force;

end Work_Force;
```